# crypto kernel module not available on Raspberry pi 2 (linux 3.18.11)

Tags: linux, kernel, encryption, raspberry-pi, deb

I'm trying to use dm-crypt on my Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian (debian) to open a trueCrypt volume, but i get

```
Required kernel crypto interface not available.
Ensure you have algif_skcipher kernel module loaded.
```

My research has yielded that algif_skcipher should be available since `2.6.38`, but my kernel version is `3.18.11-v7+` (according to `uname`). Why isn't the module available and, more importantly how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Raspbian. What I'd do is try `modprobe algif_skcipher`. If that doesn't work, look in `/lib/modules` for a file called `algif_skcipher.ko`. If there is one, try to find out what's wrong with `modprobe`. If there isn't one, then the distro elected not to compile that particular module and the only way forward would be do your own kernel compilation, which is hard to get right even for PC, let alone for Raspberry Pi.